# Adding a custom themable variable in theme_preprocess_page

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have read the docs over and over trying to wrap my head around this seemingly simple task. Basically, I have a template with a 'skip navigation' div hard-coded in html.tpl.php that I *do not want* on front-page.

My idea was to set a $vars['skiplink'] variable in theme_preprocess_page. Since this variable contains a few lines of html markup, I was aiming for something as seen in garland theme:

```
function garland_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  // Move secondary tabs into a separate variable.
  $vars['tabs2'] = array(
   '#theme' => 'menu_local_tasks',
   '#secondary' => $vars['tabs']['#secondary'],
  );

 <snip>
```

I would like to have the html in a themable function or even a template, but I cannot even get this snippet to work:

```
/**
 * Override or insert variables into the page template.
 */
function morin_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  // add skiplink markup
  $vars['skiplink'] = 'hello world';
 }
```

This generates a notice:

*Notice : Undefined variable: skiplink in include() (ligne 14 in /var/dev/morin/www/sites/all/themes/morin/templates/html.tpl.php).*

Can anyone slap me with a clue? I would really like to understand how to do this with both methods, ( template & function ). I'm also wondering if this should be done in a module?

I realise there are probably 10 ways to skin this cat, so any insights on pros/cons of methods used are welcome.

Ok I figured out I was using the wrong preprocess function, setting $vars['skiplink'] in preprocess_html is the way to go for top-level variables.I still have yet to figure out in a clear way how to associate this variable to a template file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preprocess hooks follow this pattern:

```
<theme name>_preprocess_<template name>
```

So if you want to modify the variables for "html.tpl.php" you want to use this hook:

```
<theme name>_preprocess_html(&$variables)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `preprocess_page` but you are inserting the variable in the `html.tpl.php`.

You should either insert it in the `page.tpl.php` or rename your preprocess function, to add the variable to the `html.tpl.php`

And remember to clear cache if you didn't have the preprocess function defined already.

**Update:**
You seem to be missing a key point. Preprocess functions (along with the actual theme call) is how you make variables accessible in templates. Different preprocess functions are called for different templates, (`..._page` for `page.tpl.php` etc.)

Do you still have problems after using the correct preprocess function and clearing cache?

Comment: I posted an update, you are right though, preprocess_html is one of 2 functions I could use for adding variables above the content level.